# loading nested defaultdict with scipy.loadmat

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am trying to load a .mat file in python.
The file was created like this:

```
import collections
import scipy.io

out_o = collections.defaultdict(list)
out_t = collections.defaultdict(list)
out_o['o1'] = {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}
out_o['o2'] = {'x':[7,8,9], 'y':[10,11,12]}
out_t['t'] = out_o
scipy.io.savemat('test.mat', out_t)
```

How can I reconstruct `out_t` from the file `test.mat` without hard coding the keys of `out_o`?

I managed to get the keys with:

```
input = scipy.io.loadmat('test.mat', squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=True)
print(list(input['t'].dtype.names))
```

> ['o2', 'o1']

But how do i access the data?

```
print(input['t'])
```

prints:

> ((array([7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12])), (array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])))

Thats as close as I managed to get to `x` and `y` ...

---

edit:

Thanks to hpauljs answer I managed to solve my problem.

I couldnt hard code the `oi`s, so I used `dtype.fields.keys()`:

```
input = scipy.io.loadmat('test.mat')
objs = list(input['t'].dtype.fields.keys())
in_o = collections.defaultdict(list)
in_t = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in objs:
    in_o[i]={'x': list(input['t'][i][0,0]['x'][0,0][0]),'y': list(input['t'][i][0,0]['y'][0,0][0])}
in_t['t'] = in_o

print(in_t == out_t)
```

Comment: What do you get without the `struct_as_record` parameter? `savemat` squeezes the data into matlab compatible structures.  It isn't designed to 'pickle' python ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save

```
In [409]: out_t
Out[409]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'t': defaultdict(list,
                         {'o1': {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]},
                          'o2': {'x': [7, 8, 9], 'y': [10, 11, 12]}})})
```

and get back

```
In [410]: R = io.loadmat('test.mat')
In [411]: R
Out[411]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Tue Jul 18 09:32:39 2017',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 't': array([[ (array([[(array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[4, 5, 6]]))]],
       dtype=[('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O')]), array([[(array([[7, 8, 9]]), array([[10, 11, 12]]))]],
       dtype=[('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O')]))]],
       dtype=[('o1', 'O'), ('o2', 'O')])}
```

`R['t']` is a (1,1) array with 2 fields, `dtype([('o1', 'O'), ('o2', 'O')])`.

```
In [417]: R['t']['o1']
Out[417]: 
array([[ array([[(array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[4, 5, 6]]))]],
      dtype=[('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

This is (1,1) object array; the element is a (1,1) array with 2 fields

```
In [424]: R['t']['o1'][0,0]['x'][0,0]
Out[424]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

To be matlab compatible, all arrays are 2d.  Dictionaries are saved as structured arrays, with a one field per key.

With `squeeze_me` indexing is bit different.  The (1,1) object arrays have been replaced by `()` (0d) object arrays.

```
In [437]: R['t']['o1'].item()['x'].item()
Out[437]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

As I commented. `savemat` saves a matlab compatible structure.  Use `pickle` if you want to save and reload Python objects.

Loading this file in Octave gives one structure, `t`:

```
>> t
t =
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    o1 =
      scalar structure containing the fields:
        x =
          1  2  3
        y =
          4  5  6
    o2 =
      scalar structure containing the fields:
        x =
          7  8  9
        y =
          10  11  12
```

---

`np.save` saves Python objects with their pickle, after first wrapping them in an object dtype array:

```
In [467]: np.save('test.npy', out_t)
In [468]: np.load('test.npy')
Out[468]: array(defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'t': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'o1': {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]}, 'o2': {'x': [7, 8, 9], 'y': [10, 11, 12]}})}), dtype=object)
In [469]: _.item()
Out[469]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'t': defaultdict(list,
                         {'o1': {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]},
                          'o2': {'x': [7, 8, 9], 'y': [10, 11, 12]}})})
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, with your help I was able to solve my problem (see question edit)